# Creating a plot in R over months

Tags: r, plot

Here is an example of my DF.

```
count month 
3     2014-10-01
4     2014-15-01
3     2014-13-02
12    2014-14-02
12    2014-18-04
```

I am trying to generate a plot in R that gives me the count on the y axis. I want to have the months on the x axis but I can't figure out how to group all january months together, february months together... etc.

`> likes <- plot(seq_along(DF$month),DF$count, type = "l",axes = FALSE, lab = "", lab = "Counts")`

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: You can try converting the dates into a [yearmon object](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.7-14/topics/yearmon), which you can then group easily, because it behaves similarly to a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or a base R and ggplot2 solution:

```
# date object
d$month2 <- as.Date(as.character(d$month),  "%Y-%d-%m")
> str(d)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
  $ count : int  3 4 3 12 12
$ month : Factor w/ 5 levels "2014-10-01","2014-13-02",..: 1 4 2 3 5
$ month2: Date, format: "2014-01-10" "2014-01-15" "2014-02-13" "2014-02-14" ...

# per month
res <- aggregate(d$count, list(months(d$month2)), sum)
# again a date object
res$month <- as.Date(paste0("01-", res$Group.1, "-2014"), "%d-%B-%Y")
# plot
ggplot(res, aes(x= month, y=x)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = "1 month",date_labels = "%B")
```

[image]

You also can try to include both, raw data as points and counts per bar plot:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x= month2, y=count)) +
  geom_point(col="red") + 
  scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = "1 month",date_labels = "%B") +
  geom_bar(data = res, aes(x= month, y=x),stat = "identity", position = 'identity',width=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, However, when I try this code on my real dataset I am getting a total count of all the counts instead of the count for just jan, feb, march... do you have any idea why?

Comment: Check if `months(d$month2)` gives you a vector with different month names. If not something did go wrong with the date transformation the step before, I guess. Check `str(your_data)`

Comment: Thank you, i figured out the problem. This works great

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to aggregate by month. However, this will not give you a time series. It will give you ordered factors. Here's how to plot that. I first `summarise` by month using `dplyr` and `lubridate`. Then for the x-axis, I transform the month factor to numeric but I don't plot it (`xaxt="n"`). I add it back with the correct format with `axis` afterwards.

```
df1 <- read.table(text="count month
3     2014-10-01
4     2014-15-01
3     2014-13-02
12    2014-14-02
12    2014-18-04",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

library(dplyr);library(lubridate)
DF <- df1%>%
group_by(month=month(ydm(month), label = TRUE))%>%
summarise(count=sum(count))

plot(as.numeric(DF$month),DF$count, type = "l",xaxt="n",main = "Counts")
axis(side=1,at=as.numeric(DF$month),labels=DF$month)
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I am looking for, thank you. When I try to run `DF <- df1%>%
group_by(month=month(ydm(month), label = TRUE))%>%
summarise(count=sum(count))` I get this error: Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: @Ashley Assuming you are referring to your real data, check `str(df1)`. The date has to be in a date format. Use `df1$month<-as.Date(df1$month)` beforehand if needed

Comment: Thank you. I realize I was making a small mistake in my code. I do have another question however, when I look at my DF after running the group_by and summarize commands, I am only seeing a total count for the month of january. In my real DF, the label of the column of the dates is `Month`. Should my group_by statement look like this? `group_by(month=month(ydm(Month), label = TRUE))%>%`

Comment: @Ashley Yes, I believe so. What's inside `ydm()` whould be the original column name

Comment: hmm, that is weird then. Im not sure why its giving me a total of all the counts over all dates instead of the total count per month .

Answer (score 0):

A solution without additional packages, introducing the beginning (or middle with -15) of the month :

```
df <- data.frame(count=c(3,4,3,12,12), day=c("2014-10-01", "2014-15-01", "2014-13-02", "2014-14-02", "2014-18-04"))

df$day<-as.Date(df$day, format="%Y-%d-%m")
df$month<-as.Date(format(df$day, "%Y-%m-01"))
df2<-aggregate(count~month, data=df, FUN=sum)
plot(df2$month, df2$count, typ="o")`
```